# Question about the chain rule in this problem.

Tags: calculus

This is a problem taken from Caluclus Early Transcendentals by James Stewart 7th edition.

My question is about how the chain rule is used to get from $m(dv/dt)$ to $mv(dv/dx)$?[image]

Comment: If you're not going to write out the problem in Mathjax, the least you could do is align the image properly.

Comment: My **guess** is that since $x$ acts as the position function, we know $dx/dt$ is the rate of change in position = velocity, so $dx/dt = v$.  Also, $dv/dt = dv/dx \cdot dx/dt$ by the chain rule (since velocity $v$ is a function of position $x$ because at each position you have a different velocity, and position is a function of time, so differentiating velocity with respect to time is differentiating it with respect to position, times the derivative of position wrt time via the chain rule, so $dv/dt = dv/dx \cdot v$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a function of time $t$ so that $x=x(t)$.

Under certain conditions, we can write the inverse function $t=t(x)$ (e.g., If $x(t)$ is differentiable with non-zero derivative, $x'(t)\ne 0$, then the inverse function $t(x)$ exists and is also differentiable).

Now, suppose that $v$ is a function of time given by

$$v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Then, as a function of $x$, we have from the chain rule that $v(t(x))$ can be written

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$$

Solving for $\frac{dv}{dt}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}\frac{dv}{dt}&=\frac{\frac{dv}{dx}}{\frac{dt}{dx}}\\\\
&=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\\\\
&=v\frac{dv}{dx}
\end{align}$$

which was to be shown!  In going from the first line to the second, we used the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx}=1/\frac{dx}{dy}$ whenever $\frac{dx}{dy}\ne 0$.

Comment: But this doesn't really explain anything.  It just lists a string of equalities.

Comment: How do you suggest I improve the answer?

Comment: I think you should explain how you arrived at this answer.  What is your justification for these equalities based on the problem stated/pictured?  This is important because it helps the user understand how you came up with this, so they can come up with it on their own in future problems.

Comment: OK.  I have taken your suggestions and added to the answer.  Let me know if you have further suggestions.  And thanks!!

Comment: Cool, thanks for expanding! :)

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And thank you again for the help!!